# C++ function returning address of static array

Tags: c++, local-variables, static-variables

In the following code block...

```
#include <iostream>

int* a() 
{
  static int nums[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  return nums;
}

int* const& b() 
{
  static int nums[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
  return nums;
}

void c( int*& num )
{
  if ( num )
  {
    std::cout << "I got " << *num << std::endl;
  }
}

void d( int* const& num )
{
  if ( num )
  {
    std::cout << "I got " << *num << std::endl;
  }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  int* nums = a();
  std::cout << nums[1] << std::endl;

  int* const nums2 = b();
  std::cout << nums2[1] << std::endl;

  int* num = new int(64);
  c( num );
  delete num;

  int num2 = 101;
  d( &num2 );
}
```

... why does function `int* const& b()` generate the following compile warning?

```
sh-4.2$ g++ -o main *.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                
main.cpp: In function 'int* const& b()':                                                                                                                                                                 
main.cpp:12:10: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]                                                                                                                          
   return nums;
```

I figure `nums` in `b()` is static, therefore in the data section of memory, so is not subject to the problem of returning an address of a truly function-local variable.

I tried compiling and running this code on my desktop and two online C++ compilers. Executable runs fine on the desktop and one online compiler, but on the second online compiler, it dies early after printing "2". But I don't have access to a core file, nor did I see a stack trace to see what actually went wrong. (Working online compiler was tutorialspoint and non-working online compiler was codechef)

I'm particularly puzzled why `b()` generates this warning and/or runtime error whereas `a()` does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `nums` is not a pointer, it is an array. Although C++ will implicitly convert it to a pointer as needed, taking a reference to the array and representing it as a pointer would require a temporary. Essentially, C++ will do this:

```
static int nums[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
int* invisible = nums;
return invisible;
```

Making a static pointer and taking a reference to it will fix this warning:

```
static int data[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
static int* nums = data;
return nums;
```

Alternatively, you could typedef a fixed-length array, and use it as the return type of `b()`:

```
typedef int array3[3];

array3 const& b()
{ 
  static int nums[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
  return nums;
}
...
array3 const &nums2 = b();
```

Comment: This is interesting. I always thought that because C++ did the implicit conversion that they were the same/interchangeable. Thanks for this answer: I learned something new.